# Extract object from on hdd ole binary

Tags: c, extract, ole, lotus

I'm having a specific issue with OLE objects embedded in Lotus Notes documents.

Users have attached f.e. Word or Excel documents as OLE objects (in Lotus Notes Document) and I need to get those original documents from OLE as file attachments that can be opened in their host applications.

Using Lotus Notes C API I have managed to detach OLE objects to HDD.
Trouble is that Word document is nested in OLE binary in directory Word.Document.8 or Word.Document.12. Just renaming OLE binary to doc or docx does not work.

This is why I have written Java OLE package that reads binary and extracts documents.
This works but...there is a downside.

I have to parse OLE class name and if it is Word.Document.8 I need to write code that manually extracts all streams from word.document.8 directory and saves them as new .doc OLE object in order for Word to open it correctly.

This is not hard for Office documents only, but all sort of things can be embedded in OLE and I cant cover all possabilities.

Is there C api function that can extract embedded objects from OLE binary (original filename is not important but extension is)?
How does it Lotus or Word do when you double click OLE object?
It has to reconstruct embedded document somehow?
I would like to do it the same way :-)

Thank you for help.

Comment: This is not about programming embedded systems.  Retagged

Answer (score 0):

try automate Notes to copy the embedded object to the clipboard then get the CF_EMBEDDEDOBJECT format from the clipboard, This is similair to how you drag an OLE item to the Windows Explorer to create a scrap file.

References & useful pages:

- ["Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios"  [msdn.microsoft.com]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904(v=vs.85).aspx#scrap)

[[CiteHistory Record](http://bit.ly/R5rVvH)]

Comment: This will not work:  
_When the Shell creates the scrap file, it represents the data as an embedding object. When the scrap is transferred to another container, it is transferred as an embedding object, even if it is being returned to the original document. Your application is responsible for determining the data format contained in the scrap and putting the data back into its native format if necessary._  
It seems I will get same OLE binary I have now.

Answer (score 0):

For extracting files in the C API, I would take a look at the NSFNoteCipherExtractFile function (and NSFNoteCipherDecrypt). If using 8.x or later.